# How to List CPTs Under One Tax Term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I am having some difficulties to get CPTs which are under one Tax Term. For Example if I have a Taxonomy Called "Movie" and Tax terms as:

- A
- B
- C

How Can I list CPTS which are in Tax "Movie" and only under B Term?

Thanks

Comment: List them how?  On an archive?  What are you trying that isn't working?  A little more info is needed for us to help please.

Comment: Hi Manny thanks for reply, what I am thinking is to create a page template for each tax term then populate the page with posts which are under that specific Tax TERM. I am not sure what exactly do you mean on archive?!

Comment: You don't need a "page" template as WordPress already has a term archive template (a page on your site that shows all the posts/CPTs in a specific term). See @Anas' answer.

Comment: Thanks helgatheviking , but what should I write inside those pages? I mean in back end?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. slug of your taxonomy is `movie`
2. slug of your term is `b`
3. you are using [pretty permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks)
4. your website is accessible at: www.example.com

You can see a list of all posts which have been assigned this specific term under this taxonomy by going to:

www.example.com/movie/b/

This page will display posts from all custom post types to which this taxonomy has been added. So, if you have added this taxonomy to just one post type then it will automatically list posts from just that post type.

You can control the display of these posts by creating/editing an appropriate template for this taxonomy or even this specific term according to the hierarchy given here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: Thanks Anas, These steps are clearly what I need to do and to be honest I have already reviewed them and my question is coming exactly from there!. Ok I know I am going to use a Regular Loop in index but what Custom Loop should I use in `archive.php` and `taxonomy.php` `taxonomy-movie.php` and `taxonomy-movie-b.php` ? This is what which is confusing me!

Comment: What do you mean by "custom loop"? You should use the exact same template tags and looping structure in all the templates mentioned by you as those in `index.php` . Only difference will be in the html that you surround those template tags in. If you would like your taxonomy archives to look different than the rest of your blog archives then you can use different html in them, apply  different ids and classes to html and then write appropriate css to style them in your desired way.

Comment: @Behseini To further make this clear, please checkout the index.php and a taxonomy archive template from a wordpress theme that I created recently for a project. You can see that the loop in both of these templates doesn't differ much.
https://gist.github.com/anaspk/b19a4bb9fdf800d4cb71#file-index-php
https://gist.github.com/anaspk/b19a4bb9fdf800d4cb71#file-taxonomy-cc_products_cats-php